# BERT not showing R shell in console

Tags: r

I have a question regarding to BERT, because it doen't show me the R shell in the console. I only see the 4 scripts (preferences, welcome, excel scripting and functions.r). I also can't execute the script functions.r and excel doesn't recognise BERT when I try to call functions from bert with application.run ( "bert.call"...).

Neža